# Strategies for debugging across devices

Tags: android

I'm having trouble with an app I published that sends user notifications.

The notifications are called from a `background service` that checks for a `boolean` that gets saved to `SharedPreferences` when the user selects to enable notifications or not.

However, I've had some users on the Galaxy S5s say that they can't turn them off (I test with nexus devs and have beta testers on m8, etc). How do I **address** this issue?

What is the strategy for solving problems that arise only for specific devices?

Comment: Please post **relevant** code.  This is highly unlikely to be device specific.

Comment: Well, it is. It works for my testing devices and the only complaints I've received are for the S5 - and the only reason I consider it an issue is because I've received several for only the S5. The relevant code is pretty simple and as described -> Service accesses SharedPrefs -> Boolean delivers notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, Android kinda sucks in that regard. There is absolutely no way to guarantee that if one piece of code that works on one device works on another one. Since Android is open source, manufacturers usually modify the firmware to make it kinda customized. However, they sometimes change things that will affect performance of a single function.

It is even worse! Your code might work on S4 with Android JellyBean, but not work with the same device Android Kitkat. Anyways, no - there is no way to debug without the actual device. However, you can log different events in your code and use an analytic service (like Google Analytics) and send the data to your database to study and figure out the problem. This is the method that I typically use in such cases.

If the problem is that the app crashes on some device. It is even easier. Users need to press on the "send crash data" button - so you can study the log on your developer account.

Comment: That's some good advice. I figured it was a firmware issue, but like you say it's a shot in the dark.

Have you got a link to the Google Analytics for app errors? I should look at adding such a mechanism. 

If the error caused the app to crash, having the logs might help.

Comment: This is the main documentation for Google Analytics - android version: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/